# Differential Equation Assistance

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, slope

use the differential equation given by dy/dx=xy/3, y>0

1. http://assets.openstudy.com/updates/attachments/553c056ce4b0a876f24412aa-ctrl_alt_l33t-1430002637234-screenshot20150425at6.58.01pm.png
2. Find the particular solution y = f(x) to the given differential equation with the initial condition f(0) = 4.

For the table, I kept on getting 3 for the dy/dx rows but I am not sure. please help!!

Answer (score 1):

hint: write your equation in the form
$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{x}{3}dx$$ and integrate both sides

Comment: after I integrate, do I just plug in the x values into the new equation?

Comment: yes we have then $$y(x)=Ce^{\frac{1}{6}x^2}$$ with a constant $C$